# On using swipe refresh in recyclerview my adapter is not getting data when it is refreshing

Tags: android-adapter, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

My Latest fragment

```
public class Latest extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView recyclerLatest;
private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRecycler;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private List<LatestAdDetails> latestAdDetailsList = new ArrayList<>();
private LatestAdapter latestAdapter;
private LatestAdDetails latestAdDetails,latestAdDetails1;
private JSONObject jsonobject;
private Context context;
private String x;

public Latest() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_fragment,container,false);
    recyclerLatest = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_latest);
    swipeRecycler= (SwipeRefreshLayout)mainView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_recycler_latest);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    recyclerLatest.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerLatest.setHasFixedSize(true);
    context = getContext();

    // url for latest add obtaining
    UrlConstants.latest_ad_obtained= UrlConstants.latest_ad+ AppController.getString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"country_id")+"/"+AppController.getString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"city_id");
    latestAdapter = new LatestAdapter(latestAdDetailsList);
    recyclerLatest.setAdapter(latestAdapter);
    latestAdd();
    swipeRecycler.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh(){refreshLatestAd();
        }
    });
    return mainView;
   }
private void refreshLatestAd() {
UrlConstants.latset_ad_refresh_obtained=UrlConstants.latest_ad_refresh+
        AppController.getString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"country_id")+"/"+
        AppController.getString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"city_id")+"/"+
        AppController.getString(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"refresh_ad")+"/"+0;

    LatestRefreshHandler latestRefreshHandler = new LatestRefreshHandler("latestRefreshADD");
    latestRefreshHandler.executeAsStringRequest(new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);

            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    if (jsonobject.getString("default_photo").isEmpty()) {
                        x = UrlConstants.default_photo;
                    } else {
                        x = jsonobject.getString("default_photo");
                    }
                    Log.e("x", x);
                   latestAdapter.clear();
                    int Ad_id_refresh = jsonarray.getJSONObject(jsonarray.length()).getInt("id");
                    AppController.setString(context,"refresh_ad", String.valueOf(Ad_id_refresh));
                    latestAdDetails = new LatestAdDetails(
                            jsonobject.getInt("id"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("cityid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("price"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("type"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("comments"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("categoryid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("MainCategoryID"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("created"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("views"),
                            jsonobject.getString("title"),
                            jsonobject.getString("default_photo"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CityName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CategoryName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("storeid"),
                            jsonobject.getString("currency"),
                            jsonobject.getString("description"),
                            jsonobject.getDouble("Latitude"),
                            jsonobject.getDouble("Longitude")
                    );
                    latestAdDetailsList.add(latestAdDetails);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            latestAdapter.addAll(latestAdDetailsList);
            latestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerLatest.setAdapter(latestAdapter);
            swipeRecycler.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, new BaseRequest.ErrorResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {

        }
    });
}



private void latestAdd() {
    LatestRequestHandler latestHandler = new LatestRequestHandler("latestADD");
    latestHandler.executeAsStringRequest(new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("response", response);

            JSONArray jsonarray = null;
            try {
                jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    if (jsonobject.getString("default_photo").isEmpty()) {
                        x = UrlConstants.default_photo;
                    } else {
                        x = jsonobject.getString("default_photo");
                    }
                    Log.e("x", x);
                    int Ad_id_refresh = jsonarray.getJSONObject(1).getInt("id");
                    AppController.setString(context,"refresh_ad", String.valueOf(Ad_id_refresh));
                    latestAdDetails = new LatestAdDetails(
                            jsonobject.getInt("id"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("cityid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("price"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("type"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("comments"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("categoryid"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("MainCategoryID"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("created"),
                            jsonobject.getInt("views"),
                            jsonobject.getString("title"),
                            jsonobject.getString("default_photo"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CityName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("CategoryName"),
                            jsonobject.getString("storeid"),
                            jsonobject.getString("currency"),
                            jsonobject.getString("description"),
                            jsonobject.getDouble("Latitude"),
                            jsonobject.getDouble("Longitude")
                           );
                    latestAdDetailsList.add(latestAdDetails);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            latestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }, new BaseRequest.ErrorResponseCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Exception exception) {

        }
    });
}}
```

my Adapter class

```
public class LatestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LatestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Context context;
private String text;

private List<LatestAdDetails> latestAddDetailsList;

public LatestAdapter(List<LatestAdDetails> latestAddDetailsList) {
    this.latestAddDetailsList = latestAddDetailsList;
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView txtTitle, txtDescription, txtCityName, txtPrice, txtCategory, txtHour, txtPhotoNo;
    private NetworkImageView imgPhoto;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_title_fad);
        txtDescription = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_fad);
        txtCityName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_name_fad);
        txtPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.price_fad);
        txtCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_fad);
        txtHour = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.hours_fad);
        txtPhotoNo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_photo_no_fad);
        imgPhoto = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_photo_lod_fad);
    }
}

public void clear() {
    latestAddDetailsList.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
 }// Add a list of items
public void addAll(List<LatestAdDetails> list) {
    latestAddDetailsList.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public LatestAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.featured_ad_adapter_layout, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LatestAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LatestAdDetails latestAddDetails = latestAddDetailsList.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(translate(latestAddDetails.getTitle()));
    holder.txtDescription.setText(translate(latestAddDetails.getDescription()));
    holder.txtCityName.setText(translate(latestAddDetails.getCityName()));
    holder.txtPrice.setText(Integer.toString(latestAddDetails.getPrice()));
    holder.txtCategory.setText(translate(latestAddDetails.getCategoryName()));
    holder.txtHour.setText(Integer.toString(latestAddDetails.getCreated()));
    holder.txtPhotoNo.setText(Integer.toString(0) + " photos ");
    try {
        imageLoader = VolleyHandler.getImageLoader();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    holder.imgPhoto.setImageUrl(latestAddDetails.getDefault_photo(), imageLoader);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    Log.e("size", String.valueOf(latestAddDetailsList.size()));
    return latestAddDetailsList.size();
}

private String translate(String myString) {

    try {
        myString = myString.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
        byte[] utf8Bytes = myString.getBytes("UTF8");
        text = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return text;
}}
```

on refreshing adapter size is zero,but getting json correctly,but not adding to adapter,and the recycler view is not showing new data,please help me ,the json is giving 10 datas on every swipe but it is not getting added to recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a logical bug :

In method : refreshLatestAd(), Remove these line :

```
latestAdapter.clear(); 
latestAdapter.addAll(latestAdDetailsList);
```

and

```
recyclerLatest.setAdapter(latestAdapter); // It need not be set again.
```

Let me know if it helps.

> latestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() is sufficient to notify the
>   adapter that the data is changed. Always modify the list
>   [latestAdDetailsList] which is being set to adapter, this is the sure
>   shot way to make the changes reflect when you call notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: then how the new refreshed data and older data is shown in Recycler adapter

Comment: You have already set the list of your adapter to latestAdDetailsList, since you are already adding the data fetched from api call to it, there is no need to reset the list, just call notifyDataSetChanged(); Adapter basically has a reference to the list already, so call notifyDataSetChanged(), That's the way adapter works.